# Why is my helper not working

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail, helper

I'm trying to add a conditional check to my New Order email template by using a helper to determine which Group a customer belongs to. My helper is loading fine, but it seems like the helper doesn't have access to any data (Customer or Order info).

`sales.xml`

```
<sales_email_order_invoice_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_invoice_items" name="items" template="email/order/invoice/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_default</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
```

`Data.php`

```
class Mbs_Emailbygroup_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function getEmailTemplate() {
    $customerGroupId = $this->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customerGroupName = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
        if($customerGroupName = 'Distributors5') {
             return 'email/order/items/order/discount.phtml'; 
        } else {
            return 'email/order/items/order/default.phtml';
        }
    }
}
```

**The Error**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mbs_Emailbygroup_Helper_Data::getCustomerGroupId() in /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/local/Mbs/Emailbygroup/Helper/Data.php on line 5
```

I've tried calling variations replacing `$this` with `$order` or using `$order = $this->getOrder()` but nothing seems to be getting any data.

### How can I check get the Customer Group within the transactional email template?

Comment: please check compiler enable or not?

Comment: Do you have <helper> node in config.xml?

Comment: where do you make the call `Mbs_Emailbygroup_Helper_Data::getEmailTemplate() `

Comment: Compiler is disabled. Helper node is present in `config.xml`. The only call to `getEmailTemplate` is the `sales.xml` layout file.

Comment: @AmitBera I just noticed this but I don't know if it changes anything. Compiler _Status_ is disabled, but Compilation **State** is _Compiled_. Could this cause problems?

Comment: yes.. may be...

Comment: Any idea how I can get the State to be _Not Compiled_? I have tried flushing Cache Storage & other caches, but it is not changing the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your are trying to get the `customerGroupId` form layout file using helper in email transaction.

as per the  ***@Rajeev K Tomy*** answer. You can get the customer group id from the current customer session.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
   $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
endif;
```

### Update :

To get the customer group id on admin order creation.

```
$customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId()
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to load from something other than `customer/session` since the email can be generated from the back end too? I think it should work in front and back end with the order, no?

Comment: @travisw Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Here `$customerGroupId = $this->getCustomerGroupId();` makes trouble because, `$this` stands for the class reference `Mbs_Emailbygroup_Helper_Data` and it does not have a method `getCustomerGroupId()` (nor in it's parent). So ultimately you are calling an `undefined method` here.

So instead of this you should call this method on a *valid/loaded customer instance*. ie

```
/** @var $customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer **/
$customer->getCustomerGroupId();
```

This can be achieved by passing a valid customer instance to your helper method `getEmailTemplate()` as a parameter and then use it within your function. Otherwise, you need to load a valid customer within the function itself and then use that instance to call `getCustomerGroupId()`

### EDIT

To get the order in your helper, try this.

```
 $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass in an instance of `$_order` (which is being worked with in a parent template file, before it calls `$this->getItemHtml($_item)` to output my template (`discount.phtml` or `default.phtml`) and retrieve the customer group from there? I don't know how I would go about getting the Order # or Customer # without passing the data into my helper.

Comment: Meenakshi's answer got things working, but I feel it is slower to load everything separately (with `Mage::get...`) than to import the `$_order` information when it is already retrieved higher in the template structure. If you know how I could accomplish this, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: see my edit.. it may work. Not sure.